# Website fails to load once I added a new razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, blazor

The basic structure of my project is:
A razor component to get and display a list of customers. On each customer in that list, there is a link to another razor page that holds more specific info about that customer accessed by an identifier pass to that razor page. When I add the razor page that holds the specific customer details to the routes folder and I try launching the website, it just loads a blank white webpage. before adding it and after removing it, the website loads like normal again. I have included some pictures that display how the details razor page is called. There is no difference in the URL and no error messages displayed. When I place a break point on the OnInitializedAsync on the customer list razor page, it is never hit, so it's not like it gets to the details page and then fails.

[image: pageroute]

[image: call]

[image: folderstructure]

Comment: Make it `@page "/Routes/CustomerDetails/{...."`

Comment: I adjusted the call to reflect how the page is set up, re-ran it but still got the same result.

Comment: Post a [mre] ...

Comment: You will need to provide more detail.  Does nothing but a blank page appear when you start up the web site or when you try to navigate to the page?  If your `CustomerDetail` page is a "Hello World" page does it load?